# Angular Create a Pipe to replace variable inside ngFor

Tags: angular, pipe

Hello i want to make a pipe that i think its useful. Users sign up in with username so thats the only variable to display their name.

So i want to make a Pipe that will replace the username variable with first and last name variable if of course its not null and if they have declared first name and last name in a form.

So username exists in db and first and last name may not. First and Last name are two variables

username is an array inside a ngfor

```
e.g. 
    **venom89890** replace with **John Doe**
```

this is what i have so far.

html

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
  {{item?.first_name | replaceUsername:item?.username }}
  </div>
```

pipe

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

  @Pipe({
  name: 'replaceUsername'
 })
 export class ReplaceUsernamePipe implements PipeTransform {

 transform(username: any[], fullname: any[]): any
 {

  if (!fullname) return username;
 }

}
```

Any help?

Comment: Would it be better that you just transform the usernames before rendering, so that there is no need of using pipes? `this.array = this.array.select(x=>replaceUsername(x.usnername)`

Comment: Agree I don't think you even need a pipe for that just simple condition in the template.
Like so `{{item?.first_name || item?.username }}`

Comment: ok but how do i put two variables inside brackets? first_name and last_name?

Comment: You can't put "two variables". What you do is (as @Yuriy showed you) you put an expression that is evaluated into a variable at runtime (during change detection cycle to be more precise). Read up on ternary operator and (lately introduced) nullish coalescing operator.

Comment: Also make sure you have correct order in `transform` method. First goes value on the left side of the pipe. Second go arguments right side `| replaceUsername:` after colon

Comment: Like this  'transform(fullname: any[], username: any[]): any' ? But i will not use the Pipe after all